# SHA256 giving different result for same string input

Tags: axapta, x++, sha256

I have simple code to generate hash code using SHA256, however, it gives different result for the same input. However, if I declare the same string value in quotes for example `_input= "test"` then it returns the same result.

```
public static System.String generateKey(System.String _input)
{
     System.Byte[] convertedArr;
     SHA256Managed sh = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
        convertedArr = sh.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes(_inputString),0, System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount(_input));
        hashCode = System.Convert::ToBase64String(convertedArr);
    return hashCode;
    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `_input`?

Comment: Please show more of your code - what is input, FNSGenerateHashDetails etc

Comment: Please don't tag [tag:c#] if you are not using it.

Comment: Does `FNSGenerateHashDetails` maybe add some "salt" to the hash input?

Comment: When you embed function calls in a function call it becomes much harder to debug. Use intermediate variables, any decent compiler will reduce the code. Write code for human understandability and debugging. Finally provide a [mcve], add this to the question alonf with text values and intermediate values such as the result of `FNSGenerateHashDetails::GetBytes` and `System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount`. Terse and to debug code is not *leet*.

Comment: I have updated the code. _input is string that can have any xml node inner text string value. however, if I copy and declare that value in quotes for example "test 1 2 3" then result is same everytime however if I pass as parameter to same function then output is different every single time. not sure what is the issue when I put value in a variable and then pass it for hashing

Comment: XML can contain dictionaries and they are unordered, that is the entries can be in any order. Again when you embed function calls in a function call it becomes much harder to debug. In particular of interest is the values of `System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes(_inputString)` and `System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount(_input)`. Put them in temporary variable and you can examine them and you will find the source of the error. You will also be able to simply the code, once you have `System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes(_inputString)` in a variable you can get the length from it.

Comment: @zaph My _inputString is always below and some text might change.

Comment: _inputString is always below   "00620171204T04091219643ContosoEntertainmentSystemUSAUS123CoffeeStreetSuite300USA0064320171127RCURDDfalse19643SEPACORERCUR20171127ContosoEntertainmentSystemUSAUS123CoffeeStreetSuite300RedmondWA98052USANL94INGB0012312312SLEVUSMF000000001SEPAARPM00195897939643USMF000000001201711172313123ContosoRetailSanDiegoUS456PeachRoadSanDiegoCA92114USANL94INGB0004862199SCORISORF70000112"    System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes gives me same byte array , also System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount gives same byte count each time I run my program but sh.computeHash is different

Comment: Add the comment contents to the question where it will not be missed and can have formatting to make it easier to understand. Then delete the comment.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer.

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

`convertedArr = sh.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes(_inputString),0, System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount(_input));`

The input to the hash is `_inputString` but the length is taken from `_input`, they are not the same. `_inputString` != `_input`.

The function defintion:

```
public static System.String generateKey(System.String _input)
```

Current code:

```
convertedArr = sh.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes(_inputString),0, System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount(_input));
```

Debuggable (semio-pseudo) code:

```
inputBytes  = System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes(_input)
inputLength = System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount(_input)
hashBytes   = convertedArr = sh.ComputeHash(inputBytes, 0, inputLength);
```

With this the input and length can easily be verified. The chance of the error is less because `_input` is only used once.

Note: In practice I would get the length from `inputBytes` but I am not fluent in X++ so I did not make that change.

Comment: Thanks zaph I am using same as yours below, _input and _inputString was type mistake. it is same. inputBytes  = System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes(_input)
inputLength = System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount(_input)
hashBytes   = convertedArr = sh.ComputeHash(inputBytes, 0, inputLength);   I have tried length from both inputLength and inputBytes , but not sure why sh.ComputeHash is different everytime. inputBytes and inputLength seem ok always. if I hard code and declare same string in program it works but not when I take it as parameters.totally clueless now

Comment: The output is different because the input is different. One way this can happen is if the length parameter is larger than the input data and in order to get the number of bytes specified it used garbage bytes that follow the actual input. Obviously `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed` works, I have not read the docs, take a good look at them if you haven't already.

Comment: You might try `ComputeHash(Byte[])` instead of `ComputeHash(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`. That would eliminate the size variable. Also does `.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes` return a `Byte[]` type? Finally try with a short string (such as "TestMe") and compare with a SHA-256 online implementation such as [HASH CALCULATOR](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/hashcalc/index), get a simple case to work.

Comment: To add my Byte[] that is passed to ComputeHash has 409 bytes i.e. inputLength = System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetByteCount(_input) = 409 , sh.ComputeHash always gives 32 bytes. can there be an issue due to my byte size that is passed for computeHash?

Comment: Yes I tried ComputeHash(Byte[]) also. System.Text.Enconding::UTF8.GetBytes also returns Byte[] which remains same. if I hard code _input=myFullStringContent it works but if I pass same string as parameter that gets stored in System.String type of variable and I get byte array for that and computeHash for that then it does not work. Not sure what is the difference between hardcoding string value and passing as parameter. I tried both ComputeHash(Byte[]) and one with passing length also

Comment: It is quite obvious and simple: if the hash is different the input data is different in some manor. Even a minor difference, one bit, will change ~1/2 of the output bits. Here is what I would do: take a hex dump of two data inputs that produce different output and run a byte compare. Just clinging to claim that the input is the same but the output is different without extensively testing/comparing is the definition of insanity.

Comment: yes that helped, it was a minor difference in 409 bytes . its resolved now thanks